# remove a widget from python file by its id

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I wonder how I can remove a widget by its id from python file. To understand exactly what I mean, let's consider this code:

.py

```
class A:
    def create(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, id='grid')
        label = Label(text="some text")
        button = Button(text="delete", on_press=self.remove)
        layout.add.widget(label)
        layout.add.widget(button)
        self.ids.main_grid.add_widget(layout)
    def remove(self, button):
        #here I should write a code that deletes the layout widget with id grid when the button is pressed.
```

.kv

```
<A>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        id: main_grid
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ids` dictionary is created when a `kv` file/string is loaded, and creating an object (with an `id` attribute) in python code does not get that object into the `ids`. So you cannot delete such an object by its `id`. You can do the removal by simply passing a reference to added widget to the `remove()` method:

```
class A:
    def create(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1)
        label = Label(text="some text ")
        button = Button(text="delete", on_press=partial(self.remove, layout))
        layout.add_widget(label)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        self.ids.main_grid.add_widget(layout)
    def remove(self, layout, button):
        self.ids.main_grid.remove_widget(layout)
```

Comment: And what if I include the content of ```create()``` method in a loop?

Comment: When I do so, only the last widget is being removed, but how can I delete the one which the pressed button belongs to?

Comment: This still removes only the last ones. When I press the first button I expect the first layout to be deleted. Isn't there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: This time it worked as I expected. Thanks a lot)